# Remove consecutive duplicates in Julia

Tags: arrays, duplicates, julia

I am quite new in Julia and I don't know how to remove consecutive duplicates in an array. For example if you take this array :

```
   `v=[8,8,8,9,5,5,8,8,1];`
```

I would like to obtain the vector v1 such that:

`v1 = [8,9,5,8,1];`

Could anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes you're right it should include 1. Sorry !

Comment: @SamyJelassi you can edit your question to include `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method could be to define:

```
function fastuniq(v)
  v1 = Vector{eltype(v)}()
  if length(v)>0
    laste = v[1]
    push!(v1,laste)
    for e in v
      if e != laste
        laste = e
        push!(v1,laste)
      end
    end
  end
  return v1
end
```

And with this function, you have:

```
julia> println(fastuniq(v))
[8,9,5,8,1]
```

But, when dealing with arrays, one need to decide if elements are to be deep or shallow copied. In case of integers, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Is it the fatest way to do it?

Comment: Pretty fast. Perhaps some optimization directives such as `@inbounds` on the `for` could help. The `push!` function is optimized so that many small `push!`es don't exercise memory allocation too often.

Comment: If the percentage of elements removed is generally small, you might want to have also a sizehint! to optimize the allocation of the output array.  Another thing to speed it up (if it is frequently the case where no duplicates are found) would be to have a function that quickly scanned for the first duplicate, and if no duplicates are found, simply return the original array, or use `copy` (depending on whether you need a copy or not)

Answer (score 7):

In [`StatsBase.jl`](http://statsbasejl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/misc.html) there is an `rle` function (Run-length encoding) that does exactly this.

Comment: Nice solution. It also uncovered a potential bug in `rle`: An empty vector yield an exception (no checks before accessing first element).

Comment: Previous comment led to PR https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/pull/154 . Essentially, the invariant `inverse_rle(rle(v)...) == v` should still work when `v` is an empty vector.

Answer (score 5):

This is a lot slower than @DanGetz's function but here is a way to do it in one line:

```
function notsofastunique(v)
  return [v[1]; v[2:end][v[2:end] .!= v[1:end-1]]]
end


>println(notsofastunique(v))
[8,9,5,8,1]
```

Maybe it's useful for someone looking for a vecotrised solution.

Comment: same idea, but perhaps clearer: ` lag( a, n=1 ) = append!( fill(NaN, n), a[1:(end-n)] );  v[v .!=lag(v)]`

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit @niczky12 one-liner solution goal, the following uses `Iterators.jl` package (very useful and slowly migrating into Base).

```
using Iterators           # install with Pkg.add("Iterators")

neatuniq(v) = map(first,filter(p->p[1]!=p[2],partition(chain(v,[nothing]),2,1)))
```

Have not done any benchmarks, but it should be OK (but slower than the longer `for` based function).

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of practicing...

Here is another little function you can use to do this, this function will work for non negative values (inluding 0) only.

```
function anotherone(v)
    v1 = zeros(eltype(v),length(v))
    v1[1]=v[1]+1
    for e = 2:length(v)
        if v[e] != v[e-1]
            v1[e] = v[e]+1    
        end
    end
    return v1[find(v1)]-1
end
```

edit:

Adding one more version, according to the input in the comments. I think this one should be even faster, maybe you could test it out :) This version should work for negative numbers as well.

```
function anotherone(v)
    v1 = falses(length(v))
    v1[1]=true
    for e = 2:length(v)
        if v[e] != v[e-1]
            v1[e] = true    
        end
    end
    return v[v1]
end
```

Comment: A little simpler would be to use logical indexing directly.  Make `v1` a logical array (`v1 = falses(length(v))`), and then set it to true in the places where you were assigning elements to it.  Now you can simply `return v[v1]`, and it'll work for all values and element types.